# Text String with Delegates in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, string, delegates, count

I was assigned the following project for my VB.Net programming course:

"Write a program using various procedures to perform the operations listed below. Call these procedures using delegates. Make sure to document your program and have the program print descriptive text along with the numbers in b. and c.

```
a) Print a text string in reverse word order. 
b) Print the number of characters in the string.
c) Print number of words in the string."
```

Now this raises a couple of questions that I have (some of which are opinion-based) relating to how I should complete the assignment.

First off, what do you guys think my teacher means by "reverse word order"? Do they mean print a text string with the word compositions going backwards (i.e. "siht si a ecnetnes"), do they mean print a text string with the whole words going backwards (i.e. "sentence a is this"), or do they mean both at once (i.e. "ecnetnes a si siht")? This is one of the opinion-based questions, but I just wanted your guys' thoughts.

Secondly, what is the syntax to produce the number of characters in a string? I already know the code necessary to get the number of words, but part b of this assignment is confusing me slightly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My opinion on a) is that the teacher wants each word in reverse order, so "sentence a is this" is correct.

Comment: Actually the "reverse word order" could also mean to display the string sorted alphabetically descending, so your sample string "this is a sentence", could be `this sentence is a`

Comment: Your first question is actually pretty good. But we can only guess, same as you. Ask your teacher. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question, the syntax to produce the number of characters in a string is:

```
Dim mystring as String = "This is a string"
Console.Writeline(mystring.Length)

// outputs 16
```

As I mentioned in my comments, my guess for your first question is that the teacher wants the words reversed, not the characters, so "this is a sentence" would appear in reverse as "sentence a is this"

Comment: However, I think the teacher wants to know the number of letters, discarding spaces.

Comment: `Length` is a property, not a method.

Comment: @Paulo The assignment says “number of characters”, not “letters”.

Comment: @Paulo, Interesting.  I suppose it's a fun exercise, but not very practical (can't think of a time in my career when I wanted to know how many non-whitespace characters are in a string).  You could in that case use the `Replace(" ", "")` method to remove spaces and then get the length.

Comment: I thank you all for your assistance. As for the "a)" part, I suppose I will stick with the idea of keeping the words whole as they are currently, and just having the sentence displayed backwards (as in "sentence a is this").

Answer (score 1):

Had a quick go at this because it sounded interesting.

```
    '   Reverse the string and then print it to the output window
    Dim ReverseArray As Array = "Print a text string in reverse word order.".ToCharArray

    '   Reverse the array to
    Array.Reverse(ReverseArray)

    '   Convert the array back into a string (should be Reversed...)
    Debug.WriteLine("Reversed string = '{0}'", New String(ReverseArray))

    '   Get the number of Characters, remember a "Space" is still a Character
    Debug.WriteLine("Number of characters in array = {0}", ReverseArray.Length)

    '   Count the number of spaces in the string, then add an extra one
    Debug.WriteLine("Number of Words = {0}", (From c In ReverseArray Where c.ToString = " " Select c).Count + 1)
```